# MySql query gets very slow with one additional AND

Tags: mysql

I have the following query which runs very quickly without problem (it could be an inner join but I put it as SELECT/WHERE for debugging purpose)

```
SELECT * 
  from count
     , kanji_info
     , kanji
 WHERE count.drama_uid = 1
   AND count.kanji_uid = kanji_info.kanji_uid
   AND kanji.kanji_uid = kanji_info.kanji_uid
```

If I add a last filter the query takes very long (jump from a few ms to around 10 seconds)

```
SELECT * 
  from count
     , kanji_info
     , kanji
 WHERE count.drama_uid = 1
   AND count.kanji_uid = kanji_info.kanji_uid
   AND kanji.kanji_uid = kanji_info.kanji_uid
   AND kanji_info.jdpt = 5
```

the column jdpt is indexed in its table, so why does it take so much time ? The first three query result in a table of 4500 entries (out of 1.5M), and then it's a matter of removing all entries where jdpt!=5, but somehow this takes ages.

For the moment I am doing the last filtering in php, but I found this kind of annoying and would like to know if I'm missing something in MySql

Thanks

Comment: `CREATE INDEX kanji_info_idx ON kanji_info(kanji_uid, jdpt)` should cover this query. I suggest to start examining execution plans

Answer (score 0):

You should use explicit join, and not the old join mode:

```
SELECT * 
from count 
     join kanji_info on count.kanji_uid = kanji_info.kanji_uid AND kanji_info.jdpt = 5
     join kanji on kanji.kanji_uid = kanji_info.kanji_uid
WHERE count.drama_uid = 1
```

You will need to have indexes at least in count.kanji_uid, kanji_info.kanji_uid, kanji.kanji_uid and kanji_info.jdpt

Answer (score 0):

By using the common JOIN syntax vs where clause.  But also, by association, if A = B and B = C, then A = C.  So, since the `count` table already has a `Kanji_uid`, you can use that to get the `kanji` join instead of through `kanji_info`.

```
SELECT 
        * 
    from 
        count c
            JOIN kanji_info ki
                ON c.kanji_uid = ki.kanji_uid
                AND ki.jdpt = 5
            JOIN kanji k
                on c.kanji_uid = ki.kanji_uid
    WHERE 
        c.drama_uid = 1
```

Your primary table is the `count` table (which not cool as count is also a reserved word in SQL at the very basic of any aggregation.

I would have the following indexes to optimize the joins, but also change the joining condition which might be giving you a Cartesian result making it generate more records somehow.

The indexes on

```
table       index
count       ( drama_uid, kanji_uid )
kanji_info  ( kanji_uid, jdpt )
kanji       ( kanji_uid )
```